# Android Emulator Google APIs unusable with Google Repository rev 20?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

I've got an app that depends on Google Play Services. I've made an AVD with Google APIs 22, but I think this problem should exist for any AVD made with Google APIs. This image (Google APIs 22) has Google Play Services v6.7.74 installed.

If I upgrade to the latest Google Repository (rev 20, as of now), I think they dropped Google Play Services < 7? This is bad because in order to make the image happy, I need to set my build.gradle dependencies to 6.+, but then the app doesn't compile because it can't find < 7 in Google Repository rev 20...

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to force Android Studio to look at Google Repository rev 19?

**It looks like the problem could also be Google Play Services rev 26. I dont know which tool includes play services.**

[image]

Comment: This is non-reproducible. Compiling with 6.+ doesn't give me any errors at resolve just a warning in terminal that newer version 7.5 is available and that its not advisable to use +.

Comment: But to answer your question, one way to go back to rev19 would be to delete the later revisions manually from class path extras\google\google_play_services. Although I am assuming your problem is that you do not have 6.+ library installed or its been removed since it says "Install Repository"